# Why does ARM say that "A link register supports fast leaf function calls"

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I have came across the concepts of link register and leaf functions recently.

I understand from previous SO reads that the LR tells where the code was previously during execution.   I also got to know that a leaf function is a function which comes at the end of the function call hierarchy.

The [ARM wikipedia page says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Instruction_set):

> A link register supports fast leaf function calls.

**Why is this claim true?**  I looked at the ARMARM (Architecture Reference Manual), and the information on the link register is minimal.

Comment: Note that modern microarchitectures tend to have hardware return-stacks that predict where the function will return to, allowing speculative execution through the return. Even processors without a link register don't actually wait for the return address to be reloaded from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some architectures (such as x86, x86_64), the return address of a function is always stored on the stack and calling a function implies accessing the main memory:

- a write to the stack when calling;
- a read from the stack when returning.

In contrast, if your architecture/ABI can jump/return without using the main memory and the parameters and return values of the callee can be passed in registers as well, the call and return to/from leaf functions can be done without involving RAM.

If the leaf function is simple enough, it might execute without touching RAM at all:

```
int callee(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}

int caller(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
  return callee(a,b) + calle(c,d);
}
```

gives (each function compiled separately by `clang -target arm-eabi -S -o- -O3`):

```
callee:
  add   r0, r1, r0
  bx    lr
caller:
  .save {r4, r5, r6, r10, r11, lr}
  push  {r4, r5, r6, r10, r11, lr}
  .setfp    r11, sp, #16
  add   r11, sp, #16
  mov   r4, r3
  mov   r5, r2
  bl    callee
  mov   r6, r0
  mov   r0, r5
  mov   r1, r4
  bl    callee
  add   r0, r0, r6
  pop   {r4, r5, r6, r10, r11, lr}
  bx    lr
```

Notice how we can avoid accessing the memory in the core of `caller` and in `calee`.

Comment: Why do you speak about the return type of a function ? The link register stores the return address, not the return value nor the return type.

Comment: @blatinox, I meant "address" :)

Comment: You can use `__attribute__((noinline))` to get that compiler output from a single compilation unit, [like this on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/YoJJGj)

Comment: Does less-frequent access to the cache-line containing the current stack really matter, though?  Won't it typically stay hot in L1 anyway?  Or do some cores not have cache?  I think this is the answer that the author of the OP's quote had in mind, I'm just saying it's probably pretty minor.

Comment: @Peter In the context of fundamental concepts of the architecture, I think an apt response would be "Cache? In a deliberately low-cost processor design? In 1985?" ;)

Comment: @Notlikethat: Oh right, that bullet list is ancient.  The header says *compared with processors like the Intel 80286 and Motorola 68020*, and one of the other points is *Conditional execution of most instructions reduces branch overhead and compensates for the lack of a branch predictor*.  In that context yes, it makes perfect sense.  My earlier comment pre-dated the OP sourcing the quote so we could see that context.  I was thinking it was still listed as a modern selling point in some ARM document.

Comment: @Peter ...that said, it's still a valid question to ask of architectures that _were_ designed to be fast, like Alpha or POWER. Alpha went so far out of the way to avoid potential pipeline interlocks that it didn't even have a dedicated link register (having looked that up to check, I am now in love with this nugget from the Alpha Architecture Handbook: _"PC-relative addressability can be established by: `BR  Rx,<label on the following line>`"_)

Comment: @Notlikethat: That's the same method x86 (32bit) uses to read EIP: `call <next line>` / `pop edi`.  call without a matching ret breaks the return-address predictor stack though, so it's usually worth using a matching `ret` to avoid branch-mispredicts on each of the next ~15 levels of `ret`s up the call tree.  (x86-64 of course has a RIP-relative addressing mode.)

Comment: @Notlikethat Actually that sounds worse. Waste of encoding space, since the calling convention has to define a specific link register anyways, and today would make implementing a return address predictor that much harder.

Comment: @Ross To the contrary, surprisingly - the branch predictor/return stack was _architectural_, and there were only three forms of branch instruction (conditional offset, unconditional offset and register). The difference between the various branch/jump/call/return/etc. mnemonics was merely the embedded branch-prediction hint. Alpha really is _nuts_ ;)

Comment: @Notlikethat Well, ok, then its just a waste of encoding space. Looking it up though, all the branch/jump mnemonics (Bxx, BR, BSR, and JSR) had their own opcodes. Only BR and BSR were functionally identical aside from the call prediction hint. They could've merged BR and BSR and gotten a larger branch offset if they didn't have the register field that's always going to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that this means that when calling the leaf function the return address does not have to be pushed to the stack (since it's stored in the link register). This is supposed to be faster than pushing the return address to the stack as you do in processors that doesn't have a link register (but it's not certain that it is actually faster).

However there are situations where the leaf function must save data to the stack anyway. For example a leaf function with many variables may need to use the stack to either store them or to save the link register to free up temporary registers.

Comment: In which ABI the link register can be used as temporary register ?

Comment: @blatinox The normal ABI. The normal way a non-leaf function returns is by poppng the return address from the stack (without restoring the link register), therefore the caller cannot assume the link register retains the value it has put in the register. It's quite usual that the link register is used this way.